# find the isolated singular points of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> find the isolated singular points of $f(z)$, and what the type of this point ?
>
> 1) $f(z)={1\over {z^2{(z-3)}^3}}$
>
> 2) $f(z)={e^{2z}\over {(z-1)^2}}$

my try:

1) the isolated singular points are 0 and 3, but what about there types ?

2)

the isolated singular point is 1

and for the Type :

$e^{2z}=1+2z+{{(2z)}^2\over 2!}+{{(2z)}^3\over 3!}+...$

so

$f(z)={1\over {(z-1)}^2} (1+2z+{{(2z)}^2\over 2!}+{{(2z)}^3\over 3!}+...)$

but what about $(z-1)^2$ ?

Comment: When does $\frac1{(z-1)^2}$ have singularities?

Comment: 1, but I don't know how can I explain the type :(

Comment: For what smallest value of $n$ does $\lim_{z\to1}(z-1)^nf(z)$ exist?

Comment: ummm, maybe 2 ?

Comment: Yup.  :-)  You can find poles that way as well

Comment: Thanks :), so for (1) : 0 is pole (order 2) and 3 is pole (order 3) ?

Comment: Yup, it's pretty much that simple.  Like simpleart :-)

Comment: No problem :-)  Just be careful though, as you need $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)^nf(z)$ to exist from all directions with $z\in\mathbb C$, and it doesn't work on essential singularities.

Comment: I will be careful for that :), Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I hope I remember everything correctly from a Complex Analysis course I took and I hope I'm not making mistakes here. I understand this answer may not be the best, but I'm trying to help anyway. :) Corrections from the community are very welcome.*

**First question:** You can write the Taylor series of the function around the singularity like $$\sum_{n = 0}^{N}a_n(z-z_0)^n +\sum_{m=1}^{M}b_m(z-z_0)^{-m}$$ If the series has infinitly many $b_m \neq 0$, then the singularity is essisential. If $b_m = 0$ for all $m$, then the singularity is isolated. If only finitely there are only finitely many $b_m \neq 0$, then the singularity is a pole of order $m$ with $m$ the highest integer for which $b_m \neq 0$

**Second question:**
Let's say $f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ with $p(z) = e^{2z}$ and $q(z) = (z-1)^2 = z^2 - 2z + 1$ and call the singularity $z_0$.

The singularity is a pole. ($\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)^2f(z)$ is neither $0$ nor $\infty$.)

If $p(z_0) \neq 0$ then the order of the pole is the lowest integer $n$ for which $$q^{(n)}(z_0) \neq 0$$

Let's see:
$$q^{(1)}(z) = 2z - 2$$
$q^{(1)}(1) = 0$, so we have to differentiate more:
$$q^{(2)}(z) = 2$$

Obviously $q^{(2)}(1) = 2$ (since it equals $2$ for any $z$), so the singularity is a pole of order $2$.

Comment: You're welcome. :) But please check if what I said is correct, I don't want you to make any mistakes because of me. ;)

Comment: (And if it helped, a +1 is appreciated :$ )

Comment: Is the power $m$ in first question negative?

Comment: @MyGlasses Indeed, it should be negative. Thanks! I fixed it.